# jsrender Template method

Tags: javascript, html, jsrender

I have use the following code snippet to render the data.

Code snippet:

```
<body>
    <div id="myGrid" style="border:1px solid red; width:500px;height:600px;">        
    </div>


    <script id="template" type="text/x-jsrender">                
        <div><div>{{:Name]}}</div></div>
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript"7>
        var helpers = {};
        helpers["templateMethod"] = Test;
        $.views.helpers(helpers);
        var data = [{ "ID": 1, "Name": "Raja" },
            { "ID": 2, "Name": "sekar" },
            { "ID": 3, "Name": "Ram" }
        ]
        var test = $("#template").render(data);
        $("#myGrid").html(test);

        function Test() {
        }
    </script>
    </body>
```

In this case i want to get the each div element while rendering for customization.

How to get this div element while rendering.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, you want to change the  to  where foo changes in each div (and "class" is just an example).  To do that, you would need either a helper, a tag, or another template.  Each have advantages.

Here is the link for [tags](http://www.jsviews.com/#tags).  I think that is most likely what you want.